# Android output error. TextView won't display output

Tags: android, loops, textview

```
package com.culligandev.www;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class threeRows extends Activity {

    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.output);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        int a = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                display.setText("*");
            }
            display.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

This activity is called by the press of a button and then should output a triangle made of asterisks like this:

```
*
**
***
```

It doesn't output anything and just shows a blank screen. Can you help, please?

Comment: it won't make a triangle, because every time you call setText it sets a new text, so the last sequence to be entered to the textview will be "", which means after you run this code, your TextView will contain "" in it

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in your "for". The last thing your app will do is display.setText(""), which means your text will be empty. You should put something like

```
display.setText(display.getText() + "\n");
```

And for the other one:

```
display.setText(display.getText() + "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

setText is not working as printf or println

if you want to display a pattern then you can do it using StringBuilder or StringBuffer
and then use that string buffer/builder object in setText to display the pattern

Comment: what would a stringBuilder look like?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/0400__StringBuilder.htm hear is the example of string builder that you might need to check

Answer (score 0):

TextView.append   might be what you're after, or use a StringBuilder as has been suggested

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
      {
                display.setText(display.getText().toString().trim()+"*");
      }
      display.setText(display.getText().toString().trim()+"\n");
}
```